# Azure Active Directory integration with SAP Cloud Foundry

Tags: azure, sap-cloud-foundry

I am trying to connect my SAP Cloud Foundry environment to Azure Active Directory.

I am following for that propose a tutorial on sap.com:
https://blogs.sap.com/2017/07/18/step-7-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-secure-your-application-on-sap-cloud-platform-cloudfoundry/
But I have a filling that a problem is on Azure side.

What I have done:

1. Configure application on in Azure Active Directory as Enterprice Application – application not from gallery
2. Configure trust option on SAP Cloud Foundry side based on SAML manifest from AZURE

What happen:

1. I try to login using SAP link
2. I am redirected to Microsoft site to provide credencials
3. After login in I have an error: AADSTS70001: Application with identifier 'my_tanant_name.aws-live-eu10' was not found in the directory 219537f5-9b6f-44ca-a674-5e49e0cfae70

My question is:

I have an application with name: 'my_tanant_name.aws-live-eu10' but maybe it is not searched by name maybe by some other filed?

Answer (score 1):

The error was simple value: "my_tanant_name.aws-live-eu10" should be placed in "App ID URI" instaead in app name.